# Not receiving firebase cloud message on ios

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions, react-native-firebase

I was working on the friend request functionality for my react-native app, and I wanted to notify the user(sender) using a cloud message if the request was accepted.
Its working successfully on Android and I am receiving the notification on the device, but its not working iOS.

This is my cloud function for accepting friend requests:

```js
//======================ACCEPT REQUEST==========================//
exports.onAcceptRequest = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const targetId = data.targetId;
  const senderId = data.senderId;
  return admin
    .firestore()
    .collection('Friendships')
    .doc()
    .set({
      targetId: targetId,
      senderId: senderId,
      timeStamp: new Date(),
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Befriended');
      notifySenderId(senderId);
      return null;
      //NOTIFICATION SENT TO uid2(senderId)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log('errrrrr', err));
});
function notifySenderId(senderId) {
  return admin
    .firestore()
    .collection('Users')
    .doc(`${senderId}`)
    .get()
    .then(doc => {
      var tokens = Object.keys(doc.data().fcmTokens);
      console.log('TOKENS: ', tokens);
      return tokens;
    })
    .then(tokens => {
      console.log('tokens: ', tokens);
      const payload = {
        notification: {
          title: 'Friend Request Accepted',
          body: 'Hi add me to a group',
          sound: 'default',
        },
      };
      return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
    })
    .then(() => console.log('notified senderId of Acceptance'))
    .catch(err => console.log('err notifying senderId', err));
}
```

On iOS the cloud function executes successfully on the backend(as shown in the functions logs below) but doesn't show notifications on the device even though I have allowed notifications in the settings.

I am not using any library to display the notifications. I expect FCM to display the notification message automatically(works on android).

Cloud Functions Log: 
[image]

EDIT: Solved it! 
I learned that fcmTokens could change over time, updating the token in the database solved my issue.

But I have a follow-up question that how do we keep track of the tokens updating on the device??

Answer (score 1):

Solved it! I learned that fcmTokens could change over time, updating the token in the database solved my issue.